# Remove row from DataSet if bound table is sorted

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, dataset

I have a `DataGridView` that is bound to a `DataSet` and I allow someone to remove a row from the table and I remove the row from the set. My code looks like this:

```
ds.Tables(0).Rows(dgCourseList.SelectedRows(0).Index).Delete()
```

My problem I found is if the grid gets sorted the index of the rows no longer corresponds to the indexes in the `DataSet`. As a result the wrong rows get removed from the set.

Can I solve this problem with maybe having to sort the DataSet on some sort event of the `DataGridView`?

Comment: are you using a `DataGrid` or a `GridView`?

Comment: I was asking about the grid component not the datasource.  You said a `DataGrid` which most people don't use anymore as it has been replaced by the `GridView`.

Comment: sorry, I am using a datagridview

Comment: thnx for clearing it up as it does make a big difference.  I have updated my answer.  Let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this but try the following assuming you have the `DataKeys` setup properly:

```
ds.Tables(0).Rows.Remove(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Find(dgCourseList.DataKeys(dg.SelectedIndex)))
```

**EDIT:** Based on you specifying that you are using a `DataGridView` which is a winforms app (I was assuming a webforms app) then you could try:

```
ds.Tables(0).Rows.Remove(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Find(DirectCast(dg.SelectedRows(0).DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row))
```

**EDIT 2:** Updated because I think the cast was wrong... still untested though.

Comment: This gives me a MissginPrimaryKeyException. Which is strange because I know there's a primary key defined in the table.

Comment: Figured out how to set the primary key in the DataSet. Now it removes the correct row from the set and grid, but when I commit, it does not delete the entry from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use the CurrencyManager to handle this.

Here's a quick article explaining the concept: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817247

```
' Get the Currency Manager by using the BindingContext of the DataGrid '
Dim cm As CurrencyManager = CType(Me.BindingContext(DataGrid1.DataSource, DataGrid1.DataMember), CurrencyManager)

' Retrieve the default DataView of the DataGrid '
Dim dv As DataView = CType(cm.List, DataView)

' Use Currency Manager and DataView to retrieve the Current Row '
Dim dr As DataRow
dr = dv.Item(cm.Position).Row

' Display the Current Row Data '
TextBox1.Text = dr(0).ToString
TextBox2.Text = dr(1).ToString
```

Using the CurrencyManager, you can retrieve the original state and go from there.

Cheers,
JS

Comment: I have read the article and I put the code in and it still doesn't work. The only thing i do differently is my line read: ds.Tables(0).Rows.Remove(dr) Do you have to sort just like they do in the article? or can you sort by the standard clicking on the column headers.

Comment: I finally figured out what going on. I have made my program to allow a user to right click a row and a context menu gives them the option to delete the row. If I right click a row the Currency Manager doesnt recognize the selected row changing. If I left click the row first then right click it does recognize the change in row and deletes the correct one.